# For a normed vector space $ E $ and an element $ x \in E $, prove that if $ L(x) = 0 $ for every continuous linear functional $ L $, then $ x = 0 $.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

> **Question.** Let $ E $ be a normed vector space. Is it true that for a given $ x \in E $, if $ L(x) = 0 $ for every $ L \in E' $, then $ x = 0_{E} $?

---

One way to prove this is to find an $ L \in E' $ such that $ \| L \| = 1 $ and $ L(x) = \| x \| $. The existence of such an $ L $ is a corollary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem, but is it really necessary to use this result here?

Comment: Consider $x$ as an element of the bidual $(E')'$. Then $x$ is linear on the normed space $E'$ with $x[L] = 0$ for all $L\in E'$. This means $x$ is identical to the $0$-functional on $E'$.

Comment: Your edit adds more clarity to the problem and also makes it **deeper**. There are two approaches: (1) Find a topological vector space in which the Hahn-Banach Theorem fails and the stated property doesn’t hold, or (2) find a model of $ \mathsf{ZF} $ containing a normed vector space in which the Hahn-Banach Theorem fails and the stated property doesn’t hold.

Comment: @Qwerty: Now, $ {L^{p}}([0,1]) $, for any $ p \in (0,1) $, is a non-locally convex topological vector space, and the only continuous linear functional is the trivial one. In a way, this shows that the Hahn-Banach Theorem is really needed.

Comment: @AlexR Actually, I don't know how to prove the injectivity of the canonical map without using that corollary of Hahn-Banach which I stated

Comment: @Qwerty What is $E'$, the space of all linear functionals or continuous linear functionals?

Comment: @Qwerty Hahn-Banach guarantees that there are lots of continuous linear functionals for normed vector spaces. That's why we need it as in Berrick's comment above.

Comment: @Qwerty: The reason why you don’t know how to prove injectivity without using the Hahn-Banach Theorem is because you *need* the Hahn-Banach Theorem. Please see my comments above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark $ 3 $ on Page $ 8 $ of [this document](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.3131.pdf) says that it is an utterly doomed enterprise to establish the statement of the OP without using the Hahn-Banach Theorem ($ \mathsf{HB} $).

If $ \mathsf{ZF} $ is consistent, then $ \mathsf{HB} $ is independent of $ \mathsf{ZF} $. Assuming that $ \mathsf{ZF} $ is consistent, there exists a model of $ \mathsf{ZF} + \neg \mathsf{HB} $. The document mentions that in every such model, there exists an infinite-dimensional normed vector space whose dual space is $ 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively concrete normed space:
$l^\infty / c_0 =: E$.  There are concrete nonzero elements, say
the coset $(1,1,1,\cdots)+c_0$.  But using only ZF, one cannot prove the existence of a nonzero bounded linear functional on $E$.

Comment: I believe that $ l^{\infty} / c_{0} $ is the Banach space alluded to by the authors of the paper referred to in my answer.